# Android Studio 3.0 asks to choose the device for every launch

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 2.X, when I launch the app for the first time, a device picker dialog opens and there is a checkbox saying something like "Use the same device for future launches". When I check this checkbox, when I launch the app again, the device chooser doesn't appear, and the app directly runs on the previously chosen device.

But in Android Studio 3.0, above mentioned check box is no longer there, so it asks me to choose the device every time I launch the app.

Is there any way to achieve the previous behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go to **Run** > **Edit Configurations** and Select emulator as Target or simply check the checkbox `Use same device for future launches`.

[image]